# Nested NIntegrate with Matrix Exponential

Tags: matrix, numerical-integration, numerical-value, nested-function, exponent

I wish to perform a numerical integration which involves a matrix exponential. Here's the following code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
MM[xp_, Δ_] := {{-I*2, 5*(Δ + 1)}, {-1, I*Δ - 11}};
PP[xx_?NumericQ, Δ_] := NIntegrate[MM[y, Δ], {y, 0, xx}];
Smat[xx_?NumericQ, Δ_] := MatrixExp[PP[xx, Δ]];
Smat2[xx_?NumericQ, Δ_] := MatrixExp[-PP[xx, Δ]];
Jmat[xx_?NumericQ, xxp_?NumericQ, Δ_] := Smat[xx, Δ].Smat2[xxp, Δ];
```

In particular, I am using `_?NumericQ` to hold the values of `xx` to ensure that I can perform a nested `NIntegrate`. I wish to evaluate the numerical integral of the product of the `1,2` and `2,2` elements of `Jmat` for some fixed parameters, namely

```
    NIntegrate[Jmat[1500, xx, 0.6][[1, 2]]*Jmat[1500, xx, 0.6][[2, 2]], {xx, 0, 1500}]
```

But I run into the following error:

[image]

It seems to me that even just printing say `Smat[xx,0.6]` returns the same output of `Smat[xx,0.6]`. I think the issue is that Mathematica cannot take the matrix exponential of `PP` since `xx` is yet to be specified. But `xx` will eventually be integrated out when I compute the final `NIntegrate` involving `Jmat`. What should I do to remedy this?

**Edit:** I understand that this can be done symbolically with `Integrate`, but the matrix `MM` is an extreme idealization of the matrix that I am actually using (in general, the matrix is `xp` dependent). Also, I will be calculating many integrals of `Jmat` so I wish to optimize the speed.

Comment: Define `f[xx_?NumericQ] := Jmat[1500, xx, 0.6][[1, 2]]*Jmat[1500, xx, 0.6][[2, 2]]` and then `NIntegrate[f[xx], {xx, 0, 1500}]`

Comment: In your more general problem, are the matrices PP [xx, delta] and PP [xxp, delta] commuting? In the simplified case you are explaining, they are indeed, so you can arrange it to a unique Matrix exponential: Jmat[xx_,xxp_,delta_]:=MatrixExp[(xx-xxp)*MM[0,delta]]